# how to set margin for flutter "MyRank in footer"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to go above the following complete layout 20px according to the photo[enter image description here

Comment: Post your code and UI Image

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

```html
  Widget myRank(String rank, String profile, String score) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
      child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            AppLocalization.of(context)!.getTranslatedValues(myRankKey)!,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(color: backgroundColor),
          ),
          leading: Wrap(children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .08,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .02),
              child: Text(
                rank,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(color: backgroundColor),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .06,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .13,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0, color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(profile)))),
          ]),
          trailing: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .06,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              score,
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
            )),
          )),
    );
  }
```